# Why Is Heroku Server Restarting Without Any Reason?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have a small game that I made for some friends, nothing big or important, so I am trying to keep it as possible. I uploaded it to heroku, everything seemed to be working fine, until I heard form some friends that their accounts keep getting deleted, and all the user levels on the game keep getting deleted. I was confused, because the users and levels are all stored in objects, and I had added no way to delete them (trust me). Whats more interesting is that I did a test, restarting my local server and my Heroku server at the same time adding an account to both, adding a level to each of those accounts, saving everything, and closing those tabs. I went back 15 minuets later and checked that both accounts and levels were still there (they were) and then closing the tabs again and going to take a break for a while (5 hours ish). When I came back, the local version still had the account and the level, while the heroku version did not have the account or the level. I had done nothing to the server (no updates, no restarts), and no one had visited the site while I was taking a break. The only thing that I could see that would cause this problem is that heroku is running `heroku restart` in the back every so often to clean up lag. Is this the case, and if so, is there a way to stop it?

Comment: When you have a free heroku account the server only runs while it is being used. I forget the idle time they use , I think 30 minutes, they shut it down to save resources and it starts up whenever a new request is made. How are you storing this data?

Comment: Ok, its just a JS object, so that is the problem

Comment: Yup.. New instance will void anything from prior memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the free plan the application sleeps after 30 minutes.

Comment: I have a worker doing a long running task, monitoring something for me. There are no requests done to the worker, in fact it doesn't even have an http listener, but it makes web requests itself. Does that count as idle?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like whatever you're trying to save, you're attempting to save it in the file system. You cannot do this on Heroku. If you want to save state/files etc. using a file system, you can use something like AWS S3 alongside Heroku.

See: [Ephemeral Filesystem in Heroku](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted)

Comment: I am not saving it in the file system on this application, but I will keep that in mind for future reference

Answer (score 1):

Here are scenarios where heroku dyno restarts :

1. After 30 minutes of inactivity If you are using the free dyno.
2. On every deployment.
3. Once in every 24(+/-1) hours even if you have paid dyno.

Comment: Small correction: every 24 hours +- 216 minutes. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting